# Understanding SQL Certificates

Tags: sql, permissions, certificate

I am having a hard time understanding how certificates in SQL work. I think I get the use of them conceptually, but when I run this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tutorial-signing-stored-procedures-with-a-certificate) from Microsoft, I realize that I may not fully understand it. If I run the script below except steps 4-5, I cannot query the Vendor table using the new user, but I can run the proc which can query the vendor table. This doesn't make sense as I thought that the user running the proc would still not be able to query that table because I haven't given permission for that table yet. Please help me understand. The full script is below:

```
/* Step 1 - Open the AdventureWorks2012 database */  
USE AdventureWorks2012;  
GO  
-- Set up a login for the test user  
CREATE LOGIN TestCreditRatingUser  
   WITH PASSWORD = 'ASDECd2439587y'  
GO  
CREATE USER TestCreditRatingUser  
FOR LOGIN TestCreditRatingUser;  
GO  

/* Step 2 - Create a certificate in the AdventureWorks2012 database */  
CREATE CERTIFICATE TestCreditRatingCer  
   ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'pGFD4bb925DGvbd2439587y'  
      WITH SUBJECT = 'Credit Rating Records Access',   
      EXPIRY_DATE = '12/05/2014';  
GO  

/* Step 3 - Create a stored procedure and  
sign it using the certificate */  
CREATE PROCEDURE TestCreditRatingSP  
AS  
BEGIN  
   -- Shows who is running the stored procedure  
   SELECT SYSTEM_USER 'system Login'  
   , USER AS 'Database Login'  
   , NAME AS 'Context'  
   , TYPE  
   , USAGE   
   FROM sys.user_token;     

   -- Now get the data  
   SELECT AccountNumber, Name, CreditRating   
   FROM Purchasing.Vendor  
   WHERE CreditRating = 1;  
END  
GO  

ADD SIGNATURE TO TestCreditRatingSP   
   BY CERTIFICATE TestCreditRatingCer  
    WITH PASSWORD = 'pGFD4bb925DGvbd2439587y';  
GO  

/* Step 4 - Create a database user for the certificate.   
This user has the ownership chain associated with it. */  
USE AdventureWorks2012;  
GO  
CREATE USER TestCreditRatingcertificateAccount  
   FROM CERTIFICATE TestCreditRatingCer;  
GO  

/* Step 5 - Grant the user database rights */  
GRANT SELECT   
   ON Purchasing.Vendor   
   TO TestCreditRatingcertificateAccount;  
GO  

GRANT EXECUTE  
   ON TestCreditRatingSP   
   TO TestCreditRatingcertificateAccount;  
GO  

/* Step 6 - Test, using the EXECUTE AS statement */  
GRANT EXECUTE   
   ON TestCreditRatingSP   
   TO TestCreditRatingUser;  
GO  

-- Run the procedure as the dbo user, notice the output for the type  
EXEC TestCreditRatingSP;  
GO  

EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'TestCreditRatingUser';  
GO  
EXEC TestCreditRatingSP;  
GO  

/* Step 7 - Clean up the example */  
REVERT;  
GO  
DROP PROCEDURE TestCreditRatingSP;  
GO  
DROP USER TestCreditRatingcertificateAccount;  
GO  
DROP USER TestCreditRatingUser;  
GO  
DROP LOGIN TestCreditRatingUser;  
GO  
DROP CERTIFICATE TestCreditRatingCer;  
GO
```

Question 1: Why can a new user with no privileges except execute on 1 proc be able to query a table in that proc? I thought their lack of SELECT permissions would still not allow them to query that table.

Question 2: If they can run anything in the proc anyway, what is the point of the certificate?

Comment: There's a GRANT SELECT in the code you posted. So there is no lack of SELECT privs that you would be implying.

Comment: The only GRANT SELECT is on the user created from the certificate, which is what I said to skip. Without that, I should be able to execute the proc using the first user created, but inside the proc, that user should not be able to SELECT from the vendor table. 2 users, but I'm not creating the second one as a test.

Comment: Oh I misunderstood and skipped to the questions to be honest. EXECUTE grants permission to the underlying objects in the stored procedure as well I believe.